# Как написать такую функцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Нужна возможность передать в одну и ту же функцию `x,z` или `x,y,z` (именно 2 или 3, не меньше и не больше) и отдавать `x,y,z`. При том что Y по барабану какое значение, т.е. можно просто отдавать y=0.

По сути это `def foo(x, y=0, z)`, но так нельзя.

Comment: Но зачем это всё?

Comment: Задаюсь тем же вопросом, встраивая такие переходники в код предыдущего разработчика, чтобы побыстрее починить косяк

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Могу предложить вариант с проверкой, введено ли третье значение

```
>>> def example(x, y, z=None):
...   if z is None:
...     z = y
...     y = 0 # то самое значение по умолчанию
...   return x, y, z
...
>>> example(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
>>> example(1, 2)
(1, 0, 2)
>>>
```

Если значения 2, что второе записывается в `y`, а потом вручную переносится в `z`

---

Проблемы могут возникнуть только в случае, если `None` - валидное значение третьего аргумента, и оно может попасть туда естественным способом:

```
example(1, 2, None)
```

---

## UPD

Дополню ответ решением через `*args`:

```
>>> def example(*xyz):
...   if len(xyz) == 2:
...     x, z = xyz
...     y = 0
...   elif len(xyz) == 3:
...     x, y, z = xyz
...   else:
...     raise TypeError('example() takes 2 or 3 positional arguments but {} were given'.format(len(xyz)))
...
...   return x, y, z
...
>>> example(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in example
TypeError: example() takes 2 or 3 positional arguments but 1 were given
>>> example(1, 2)
(1, 0, 2)
>>> example(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
>>> example(1, 2, 3, 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in example
TypeError: example() takes 2 or 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Это решение устойчиво к типам аргументов, и наличие агрумента `None` ему никак не навредит

Comment: Спасибо, думал туда же, правда про None не думал. Читал про арги и кварги, думал длину массива проверять.

Comment: @keltkelt `*args` - тоже неплохой вариант, кстати. Если интересует, могу подходящий код в решение добавить

Comment: Буду благодарен за пример

Comment: @keltkelt дополнил ответ

Answer (score 1):

как насчет того чтобы передавать параметры с именем аргумента в функцию

```
def foo(x, y=0, z=0):
    pass

foo(x=5, z=3)
```

Comment: Нужно чтобы именно 2 или 3 аргумента - не больше и не меньше. Поправлю описание сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

```
def example(default=('x', 'y', 'z'), n=0, **kw):
    return [kw.get(k, n) for k in default]

print(example())  # [0, 0, 0]
print(example(x=1, z=2))  # [1, 0, 2]
```